# Kibana 4 not the good date in visualize menu

Tags: date, elasticsearch, data-visualization, kibana-4

I have a problem with visualization of my data on Kibana 4. In discover menu I have the real date that I have insert, but in visualize menu it's not the same date.

This is my data :

```
{"index":{"_id":"1"}}
{"data1":912914,"date":"2015-01-01","title":"my-title","data2":2939186,"data3":226447}
{"index":{"_id":"2"}}
{"data1":910145,"date":"2015-01-02","title":"my-title","data2":2936572,"data3":225800}
{"index":{"_id":"3"}}
{"data1":917742,"date":"2015-01-03","title":"my-title","data2":2942237,"data3":226889}
{"index":{"_id":"4"}}
{"data1":911823,"date":"2015-01-04","title":"my-title","data2":2925900,"data3":230025}
```

And the result in discover menu :
[image: http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=402066Kibanadisco.png]

This result is good with the good date, but now in visualize menu :
[image: http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=566952Kibanavisu.png]

So, as you can see, on the second image the date is the date from the day before and note the real date as I want.

Someone can help me to resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Elasticsearch stores all dates in GMT.

When kibana displays dates, it displays them in your browsers local time (which appears to be offset from GMT by 1 hour).

If you put the times into ES with the correct time zone it may display them properly, but you have not specified how you are getting the data into ES.  If it is with logstash, you could try adding a `timezone` parameter to your `date` filter.

Comment: To insert the data, i directly insert it with curl in console and I make a mapping on the data to specify the date format like that :           _D:\curl\curl.exe -XPOST "localhost:9200/index/type/_bulk?pretty" --data-binary @data.json -d "{""type"":{""properties"":{""date"":{""type"":""basic_date"",""format"":""YYYY-MM-dd""}}}}"_

Comment: Note that timezone support is now available as of [Kibana 4.3](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/1600) that's been released on Nov 24th, 2015.